# How do I include record relationships in validation?

Tags: relations, validation, records

Say I have a record defining a foreign key relationship which is set to required, such as:

```
public function defineRelations()
{
    return [
        'type' => [
            static::BELONGS_TO,
            'Events_EventTypeRecord',
            'required' => true,
            'onDelete' => static::CASCADE
        ]
    ];
}
```

If I try to save the record with `typeId` not set I'll eventually get a database exception but the error won't show up if I call `$record->validate()`.

How do I make a relationship fail validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yii/Active Record won't do this by default.  You'd need to manually add an [exists](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CExistValidator) validation rule to the `typeId` attribute to get it to behave like you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I have that working now. If I wanted to add the code to this the question to help others, what's the etiquette? Do I update my question or add my own answer?

Comment: @JamiePittock I'd go ahead and request that Brad update his answer to include more details and add your own answer with the example that worked for you.  As a reader, I'd vote up the answer with an explicit example and like the separation of question and answer so answers can be voted up independently.

Comment: @BenParizek Yeah, on mobile. I can update it when I'm back at a real computer or feel free to add a separate answer Jamie because there's a 90% chance I'll forget, too.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've posted a separate answer. It was a bit trial and error to figure out but hopefully it'll help the next person looking.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Brad for pointing me in the right direction.

I added this `rules` method to my record.

```
public function rules()
{
   $rules = parent::rules();

   $rules[] = [
       'typeId',
       'exist',
       'allowEmpty' => false,
       'attributeName' => 'id',
       'className' => 'Craft\Events_EventTypeRecord',
       'message' => 'You must enter a valid type'
   ];

   return $rules;
}
```

`exist` is [a shortcut](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/framework/validators/CValidator.php#L64) to Yii's built-in [CExistValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CExistValidator) validator. The other key => value pairs are properties of that built-in validator.

You could also do it as a separate validator class. Something like:

```
<?php namespace Craft;

use CExistValidator;

class Events_EventTypeExistValidator extends CExistValidator
{

    public function validateAttribute($object,$attribute)
    {
        $this->message = "You must enter a type";
        $this->allowEmpty = false;
        $this->attributeName = 'id';
        $this->className = 'Craft\Events_EventTypeRecord';

        parent::validateAttribute($object,$attribute);
    }
}
```

If you did it this way your record's `rules` method would include:

```
public function rules()
{
   $rules = parent::rules();

   $rules[] = ['typeId', 'Craft\Events_EventTypeExistValidator'];

   return $rules;
}
```